# Adjust tag for SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Merge and keep [sql-server-localdb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-localdb) since it indicates DBMS, less confusion unless other DBMS has similar editions:

[sql-localdb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-localdb)

[sql-server-localdb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-localdb)

Comment: I saw it on mobile after I edited the tag wiki and I definitely agree

Comment: Thanks for posting this request. I created the [tag:sql-server-localdb] tag before seeing that there were other questions already in the `sql-localdb` tag. I didn't know tags could be merged and was going to get rid of the `sql-localdb` tag since `sql` is too generic, but then didn't know what to do when I saw that it did have questions already using it.

Comment: @srutzky - since there are "only" 10 questions tagged with that, it's pretty simple to just retag the questions with [tag:sql-server-localdb]

Comment: If anyone has 5 rep in [tag:sql-server-localdb] they can suggest a synonym here:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/sql-server-localdb/synonyms

Comment: @MaxVernon Thanks for that info, and for your help on switching those 10 questions over :-).

Comment: my pleasure!  I think the new tag is much better than the old one.

Comment: So far I have not seen the synonym for the tag updated. If that has been done the individual that does it can answer the question and I will mark it as such, and update the tag on the question.

Comment: That I don't know,probably. However I would think it best to go ahead and just setup the synonym just to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sql-localdb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-localdb) tag was automatically deleted after the manual retagging was completed. I have created the synonym from [sql-localdb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-localdb) to [sql-server-localdb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-localdb) as requested.